# python sqlite3 string object not callable

Tags: python, sql

```
import sqlite3

class DiseasesPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_con()
        self.create_db()

    def create_con(self):
        self.con = sqlite3.connect('Diseases')
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()


    def create_db(self):
        self.cur.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Diseases""")
        self.cur.execute("""
            create table diseases(
            Overview text,
            Symptoms text,
            ['When to see a doctor'] text,
            Causes text,
            ['Risk Factors'] text,
            Complications text,
            Prevention text,
            Diagnosis text,
            Treatment text,
            ['Lifestyle and home remedies'] text,
            ['Preparing for your appointment'] text,
            ['Departments that treat this condition'] text,
            URL text
            )
            """)


    def store_item(self,item):
        self.cur.execute("""insert into Diseases values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"""(
            item["Overview"][0],item['Symptoms'][0],item['When to see a doctor'][0],item['Causes'][0],item['Risk Factors'][0],
            item['Complications'][0],item['Prevention'][0],item['Diagnosis'][0],item['Treatment'][0],
            item['Lifestyle and home remedies'][0],item['Preparing for your appointment'][0],item['Departments that treat this condition'][0],
            item['URL'][0]))

    def process_item(self, item, spider): #the function which handles the dictionary 
        self.store_item(item)
        return item
```

Hello, I am trying to use this pipeline to write dictionary to sqlite database. I was storing to CSV (working fine) but I moved SQL,I am using the above class where I pass my dictionary to it to store in table "Diseases".

I getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/timmy/test/pipelines.py", line 49, in process_item
    self.store_item(item)
  File "/home/timmy/test/pipelines.py", line 46, in store_item
    item['URL']))
```

Comment: Typo: I think you want a comma between your string literal and your subsequent arguments in `def_store_item`

Comment: @khelwood which line please

Comment: After `"""insert into Diseases values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"""` and before `(`

Comment: @khelwood  thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a comma

```
import sqlite3

class DiseasesPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_con()
        self.create_db()

    def create_con(self):
        self.con = sqlite3.connect('Diseases')
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()


    def create_db(self):
        self.cur.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Diseases""")
        self.cur.execute("""
            create table diseases(
            Overview text,
            Symptoms text,
            ['When to see a doctor'] text,
            Causes text,
            ['Risk Factors'] text,
            Complications text,
            Prevention text,
            Diagnosis text,
            Treatment text,
            ['Lifestyle and home remedies'] text,
            ['Preparing for your appointment'] text,
            ['Departments that treat this condition'] text,
            URL text
            )
            """)


    def store_item(self,item):
        self.cur.execute("""insert into Diseases values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""",(
            item["Overview"][0],item['Symptoms'][0],item['When to see a doctor'][0],item['Causes'][0],item['Risk Factors'][0],
            item['Complications'][0],item['Prevention'][0],item['Diagnosis'][0],item['Treatment'][0],
            item['Lifestyle and home remedies'][0],item['Preparing for your appointment'][0],item['Departments that treat this condition'][0],
            item['URL'][0]))

    def process_item(self, item, spider): #the function which handles the dictionary 
        self.store_item(item)
        return item
```

Comment: I think this comma wasn't needed when python 2.7, anyway this works

Comment: @wishmaster No, it was always needed.